# How to save multiple files using powerapps attachment control?

Tags: attachment, powerapps

I want to find a workaround in saving multiple files using the powerapps attachment control

I already used the Last() function and converting it to base64 file then upload it on google drive. Now, I want to apply this to multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

To save multiple files using PowerApps attachment control, you'll need to follow these general steps:

Set up the Data Source:

Make sure you have a data source connected to your PowerApp where you want to save the attachments. This could be a SharePoint list, a OneDrive folder, or any other supported data source.
Add an Attachment Control:

Drag and drop an attachment control onto your PowerApp screen. This control allows users to upload and view attachments.

Configure the Attachment Control:

Select the attachment control and go to the properties panel.
Set the DataField property to the name of the field in your data source where you want to store the attachments.
Add a Button or Trigger:

Add a button or trigger that will initiate the process of saving the attachments.
Configure the Button/Trigger:

Set the OnSelect property of the button or trigger to a formula that extracts the attachments from the attachment control and saves them to your data source.

Handle Errors and Provide Feedback:

Add error handling logic in case the saving process encounters issues. You can use functions like Patch, Collect, or specific data source functions to save the attachments.
Test and Debug:

Test your PowerApp to ensure that attachments are being saved correctly. Debug any issues that arise.

Example code:
ForAll(AttachmentControl.Attachments,
Collect(
'YourDataSource',
{
Title: TextInputTitle.Text,  // Additional data you want to associate with the attachment
Attachment: Attachment
}
)
)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a Rich Text Input Control:

Drag and drop a Rich Text Input control onto your PowerApps screen.
Insert an Image Control:

Insert an Image control (Insert > Media > Image) on your screen. This will be used to display the images.
Create a Collection to Store Images:

You'll need to create a collection to temporarily store the images before saving them to your data source.
Example code:
ClearCollect(
ImageCollection,
{
ID: Guid(),  // Assign a unique ID to each image for identification
ImageData: ""  // Placeholder for image data
}
)

Set the Default Value of Rich Text Input:

Set the Default property of the Rich Text Input control to the following formula:
Concat(
ImageCollection,
"",  // Render image with its unique ID
"
"
)

This formula will render images based on their IDs in the Rich Text Input control.

Handle Pasting Images:

Use the OnChange property of the Rich Text Input control to trigger actions when the content changes.
Example code:
ForAll(
Filter(
Split(
RichTextInput1.HtmlText,
"*")
),
Collect(
ImageCollection,
{
ID: Left(
Result,
IndexOf(
Result,
"'>"
)
),
ImageData: ""
}
)
)

This code extracts the IDs of the pasted images and adds them to the ImageCollection.

Handle Image Upload:

Implement an upload mechanism (e.g., using the Add Picture control) to allow users to upload the actual images.
Example code for a button click event:
ForAll(
ImageCollection,
UpdateIf(
YourDataSource,  // Replace with your actual data source
ID = ThisItem.ID,
{
ImageData: YourImageUploadControl.Image  // Replace with your actual image upload control
}
)
)

This code updates the ImageData field in your data source with the uploaded image.

Display Images:

Use the Image control you added earlier to display the images.
Set the Image property of the control to:
LookUp(
ImageCollection,
ID = YourDataSource.ID  // Match the images with your data source
).ImageData